# Intuition behind a step in Bonnet's theorem in Riemannian Geometry

Tags: geometry, riemannian-geometry

I was going through the proof of Bonnet's theorem which says:

> **If $M$ be complete connected Riemannian manifold whose all sectional curvatures are bounded below by a positive constant $\frac{1}{R^2}$. Then $M$ is compact with finite fundamental group and with diameter less or equal to $\pi R$**.

I understand the concept of the proof.  I just have one doubt: *we have taken $E$ be any parallel normal unit vector field along $\gamma$ (where $\gamma$ is chosen to be minimizing geodesic segment between $p$ and $q$ of length $L>\pi R$. Then we have taken $V(t)= \sin(\frac{\pi t}{L})E(t)$ to be proper normal vector field $V$ along $\gamma$ and then we showed index form $I(V,V) < 0$ which is contradiction of the minimizing property.*

My doubt is **what is the specific reason to take $V(t)$ in this particular form involving $\sin$ function? Using this we are getting $V(0)=V(L)=0$. But could we take any other function other than sine one such that it is smooth and vanishes on $0$ and $L$? I am not clear the intuition behind taking sine function? Any comment or idea is very much appreciated.**

Comment: The idea is to compare the geometry of $M$ with that of a round sphere of radius $R$. In this latter particular case, $\sin(\pi t/L)V(t)$ is a Jacobi field along a path joining two antipodal points and is closely related to the index form. This is the reason to consider such a vector field along a path of length $> \pi L$ in $M$.

Comment: Oh ok now I got the intuition behind using this particular V. Thanks a lot.